# Limit file types to be uploaded

Tags: c#, file-upload, file-extension

I want to limit the types of files that are uploaded to my site. Im using this function below. Would I write if statements for `.jpg || .gif || .jpeg || .png`.
I don't want people uploading `exe`'s. What is the best way to do this?

```
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    try
    {
        var FileExtension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        var Myguid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");

        //Check to make sure its an allowable file to be uploaded???????????        

        var newName = Guid.NewGuid() + FileExtension;
        //Map path to folder
        string realpath = Server.MapPath("Pictures\\") + newName;

        //FileUpload1.SaveAs("C:\\Users\\josh\\Desktop\\JaysVersion\\PicRatingSite\\PicRatingSite\\Pictures" + FileUpload1.FileName);
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(realpath);

        Label1.Text = "File name: " +
             FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName + "<br>" +

             FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength + " kb<br>" +
             "Content type: " +
             FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType;


        InsertMembers insert = new InsertMembers();
        int age = Int32.Parse(txtAge.Text);
        insert.InsertNewMember(txtEmail.Text, Myguid, txtName.Text, txtCity.Text, txtState.Text, txtDescription.Text, age, gender);


        //Get Member Id to Insert into Pictures table
        GetMemberInfo GetID = new GetMemberInfo();
        int UMemberId = GetID.GetMemberId(Myguid);
        Displayme.Text = newName.ToString();

        //Now that i have member Id Lets insert new picture into picture table
        Picture InsertnewPictures = new Picture();
        int insertpics = InsertnewPictures.InserNewPicture(UMemberId, newName, 0);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Handle the error
        throw ex;
    }
else
{
    Label1.Text = "You have not specified a file.";
}
```

Comment: I don't think there's any other way than looking at the files collection to see what type of file has been uploaded. This is easy enough to do, but it unfortunately means that you can only check this AFTER files have already been sent. In newer browsers you can specify the file extensions to allow on the FILE control displayed on the client.

Answer (score 1):

Do NOT trust the filename the user provides. It's trivial to hack, and someone can easily do "rename nastyvirus.exe cutekittens.jpg" prior to upload. You must user server-side mime type detection to ensure that you really did get an image. Same goes for the MIME type provided by the remote browser. It can also be trivially forged and make "nastyvirus.exe" show up as "text/plain".

Comment: Do you have a simple example of how to do this? Very new to Csharp.

Comment: Sorry, never worked with C# personally. This just general advice. Never trust anything a remote user sends, especially when it comes to form data and file uploads.

Comment: Some years ago, I've written [a small content detection library](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/ContentDetectorLib.aspx) which might help as a starter.

Answer (score 0):

you can filter the type of the file to be upload using a switch statement

```
var FileExtension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);

switch(FileExtension.ToLower())
{
    case".jpg":
    case".png":
    case".gif":
    case".jpeg":
        break;
     default:
        Response.Write("this file type is not allowed");
        return;
}
```